# When to use Multiple Imputation over Maximum Likelihood for Missing Data and vice-versa?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I've seen these being called the best techniques for dealing with missing data. But I'm wondering when to use one over the other and why?

Edit: Why is this getting downvotes? I'm legitimately curious and can't find anything about it online. 
I found something like [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10705511.2011.607721?scroll=top&needAccess=true) but access to closed off to the public.

Comment: Regarding access: https://sci-hub.tw

Comment: @Alexis Thank you, but I can't access that link. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: Likely blocked by your ISP. You can search for mirror links, or IP addresses.

Comment: When i search for "multiple imputation full information maximum likelihood" I get loads of hits for free resources. Perhaps you could edit your question to give more detail about what you think the issues are and what else you need to know?

Comment: They are aysmptotically equivalent. Sometimes it's just easier to use one of them.

Comment: @mdewey Sure but the hits don't explain the advantages and disadvantages of using MI over ML and vice versa and explain why. The first [hit](https://statisticalhorizons.com/ml-better-than-mi) explains why ML over MI but not the other way around. This [hit](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/missing-data-two-recommended-solutions/) tells me some advantages or disadvantages but doesn't tell me why. I don't have a strong background in stats and I'm looking for a high level explanation of the advantages and disadvantages. I guess my question is vague but I'm looking for the whole breadth.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Hey I got a Quora god to answer my question. I'm very honored and as a social scientist, I look up to what you do have accomplished in life.

Comment: My first thought was "I didn't know MDewey was on Quora." Thanks. I just muddle through and got lucky a couple of times.